# Javascript error (object doesn't support this property or method) in IE 8 and below

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Script works fine in Chrome, Firefox, and IE 9 and 10 but not IE 7 or 8. The error I get is

Line: 53
Char: 1
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method
Code: 0

line 53-64 is

```
  calc = function(obj){
  /* get the sibling objects */
  objN = obj.name.match(/\d+$/); //get the object number so we can find it's siblings
  f = obj.form
  start_hr = eval('f.start_hr'+objN); 
  start_min = eval('f.start_min'+objN)
  start_time = eval('f.start_time'+objN)
  end_hr = eval('f.end_hr'+objN)
  end_min = eval('f.end_min'+objN)
  end_time = eval('f.end_time'+objN)
  break_hr = eval('f.break_hr'+objN)
  break_min = eval('f.break_min'+objN)
```

Comment: Omg, these evil evals!! Use `f["start_hr"+objN]`, `f["start_min"+objN]` and so on.

Comment: Did lint your code? Can we see the full source?

Comment: Should be working in older IEs too. Are you sure the error message targets this code? Especially IE7 may point out a line in HTML, where there is an inline eventhandler, and the actual error may have occurred in another file...

Comment: O.o I really hope your indentation is an accident. You also need a lot of semicolons, I am not surprised your code is buggy like this. And, as already pointed out... evals.